# Equivalent of models.Manager for SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, django, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy and I what I liked with Django ORM was the Manager I could implement to override the initial query of an object.

Is something like this exist in SQLAlchemy? I'd like to always exclude items that have "visible = False", when I do something like :

```
session.query(BlogPost).all()
```

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**EDIT:** the original version almost worked.  The following version actually works.

It sounds like what you're trying to do is arrange for the query entity to be something other than `SELECT table.* FROM table`.  In sqlalchemy, you can [map any "selectable"](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/mapper_config.html#mapping-a-class-against-arbitrary-selects) to a class;  There are some caveats, though;  if the selectable is not a table, inserting data can be tricky.  Something like this approaches a workable solution.  You probably *do* want to have a regular table mapped to permit inserts, so the first part is a totally normal table, class and mapper.

```
blog_post_table = Table("blog_posts", metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('visible', Boolean, default=True),
    ...
)

class BlogPost(object):
    pass

blog_post_mapper = mapper(BlogPost, blog_post_table)
```

Or, if you were using the declarative extension, it'll all be one

```
class BlogPost(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'blog_posts'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    visible = Column(Boolean, default=True)
```

Now, we need a `select` expression to represent the visible posts.

```
visible_blog_posts_expr = sqlalchemy.sql.select(
        [BlogPost.id,
         BlogPost.visible]) \
    .where(BlogPost.visible == True) \
    .alias()
```

Or, since naming all of the columns of the desired query is tedious (not to mention in violation of DRY), you can use the same construct as `session.query(BlogPost)` and extract the 'statement'.  You don't actually want it bound to a session, though, so call the class directly.

```
visible_blog_posts_expr = \
    sqlalchemy.orm.Query(BlogPost) \
    .filter(BlogPost.visible == True) \
    .statement \
    .alias()
```

And we map that too.

```
visible_blog_posts = mapper(BlogPost, visible_blog_posts_expr, non_primary=True)
```

You can then use the `visible_blog_posts` mapper instead of `BlogPost`s with `Session.query`, and you will still get `BlogPost`, which can be updated and saved as normal.

```
posts = session.query(visible_blog_posts).all()
assert all(post.visible for post in posts)
```

---

For this particular example, there's not much difference between explicit `mapper` use and declarative extension, you still must call `mapper` for the non-primary mappings.  At best, it allows you to type `SomeClass.colname` instead of `some_table.c.colname` (or `SomeClass.__table__.colname`, or `BlogPost.metadata.tables[BlogPost.__tablename__]` or ... and so on).

The mistakes I made in the original example, which are now corrected.  I was missing some missing `[]`'s in the call to sqlalchemy.sql.select, which expects the columns to be in a sequence.  when using a `select` statement to `mapper`, sqlalchemy insists that the statement be aliased, so that it can be named `(SELECT .... ) AS some_subselect_alias_5`

Comment: I'm using the Declarative way, could you update your example with that? (I can't make it work :/) By the way, which is best ? declarative or yours ?

Comment: neither is *better*, but declarative is certainly more convenient;  I prefer it.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the change as the declarative way and the indications! :) It works now. Is it possible to  use the new `visible_blog_posts` instead of a OneToMany key in my table ? (like get_all_blog_posts in my Blog model)

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking.  you should ask a new question so you can elaborate on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do e.g.

```
session.query(BlogPost).filter_by(visible=True)
```

which should give you just the posts you need.